# Script will not print in head if path to file is correct

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with a rather hackish implementation, where `header.php` has this line: `include_once "tracking.php";`. Inside `tracking.php`, there are these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/themename/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/themename/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

However, as long as the paths to those .js files are correct, they don't get printed in the page's head. If I introduce a typo so that the path is incorrect, then they do get printed!

I realize this is not an optimal way of including these files. However, does anyone have an idea as to why they aren't being printed if the path used is correct?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `locate_template()` for the inclusion and `wp_enqueue_script()` for the scripts? There's also `content_url()` to target /wp-content/.

Also: How did you inspect it? Sourcecode? FireBug? Try to open source in FF and then click the link. If you get a "file not found", you know what it's about, else it should be loaded. The fact that it really doesn't get "printed" to the screen is something I never saw before (in the way) you described. Best solution would be the first paragraph of my A: Switch method of inclusion and stop worrying :)

Comment: Same result if I do it the 'correct' way - nothing gets printed to the screen (viewed with Firebug, Chrome inspector, viewing the page source, etc.) as long as the path is correct. If it's incorrect, then I have no trouble getting it to show up in source. That doesn't really accomplish anything, though ;).

Comment: hm... sounds extremly strange. Have you tried putting it into a function inside functions.php? Then adding it to `wp_head()` maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

try

```
get_template_part('tracking');
```

as a way of including that file rather than the straight include.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the path for `get_template_directory_uri()` like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

You could also use `TEMPLATEPATH` to get the path, not the uri. But anyway, why don't you just include those lines directly in the header?

**UPDATE**

If you like to use `wp_enqueue_script` you have to remember hook it to an action, so your `tracking.php` would look like this:

```
function register_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquerycookie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquerycookie');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts');
```

That will register the new script (`/js/jquery.cookie.js`) and print it with the other scripts. I'm not sure if it's really necessary to include jQuery as it should be already included, just to be sure you can add this at the beginning of the function:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js');
```

As I said, it's not necessary as jQuery should be included by default, but who knows.

Comment: Small note - `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook should be used for enqueue, not `wp_print_scripts`. Also you don't need to queue jQuery explicitly if you queue another script that has it listed as dependency.

Comment: Thanks, didn't noticed about `wp_enqueue_scripts`, and yes, I had the feeling that the jQuery queue was too much. Still I'll leave it on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_enqueue_script()` can handle the ability to include javascript instantly as well as check for dependancies.

A simple php function: `<?php wp_enqueue_script('jQuery') ?>` in the your `tracker.php` file (or the `header.php`) will load jquery instantly.

You then your other script `<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery_cookie', TEMPLATEPATH. 'js/jquery.cookie.js', 'jquery')`

And finally together:

```
    <?php 
    function mysite_init() {
        if (!is_admin()) { // only fire this on non-admin pages
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery_cookie', TEMPLATEPATH. 'js/jquery.cookie.js', 'jquery'); 
}
    }
    // Add your hook to fix issue #11526 http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11526
    add_action ('init', 'mysite_init');
    ?>
```